# How to extract year, month, date from a date column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to extract date information from a date column, and append the new columns to the original `dataframe`. However, I kept getting this message saying I cannot use `.dt` with this column. Not sure what I did wrong here, any help will be appreciated.

Error message that I got in python:

[image: error message that I got in python]

Comment: youre using `.dt` on `interactions`and not on `df_review_data['Review Date']`

Comment: When I used .dt on df_reivew_date['Review Date'], the error message says"DatetimeProperties' object has no attribute 'Year'. That's why I switched to interactions.dt, wan't sure..

Comment: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 1):

First do `df.datecolumn = pd.to_datetime(df.datecolumn)`, then live happily ever after.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you year, month and day in that month. You can also easily get week of the year and day of the week.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['1920-01-01'], ['2008-12-06']], columns=['Date'])

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['Year'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x : x.year)
df['Month'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x : x.month)
df['Day'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x : x.day)

print(df)
```

In your `Time` list you have a typo `Dayorweek` should be `dayofweek`.

Comment: I have just ran the code in my answer with an additional line `df['DoW'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x : x.dayofweek)`, and it outputs correct values. Does this code produce an error when you try to run it?

Comment: if I just copied and pasted your code, it worked. But not with the dataset I had, I think it's not reading the column of 'Review Date' correctly using this method. When I did this earlier, I got an empty dataframe with just the columns of names showing. And showing the error message (str objct has no attribute 'year')    (ya, I fixed the typo. Thank you!)

Comment: So if you just replace `'Date` in my code with `Review Date`, it does not work? What doesn the last error message look like?

Comment: Also, in your original code, in first line you get `datetime` conversion in `df_review_date` dataframe, but in your 3rd line you refer to original dataframe `interactions`, where no conversion was made, hence `.dt`  is applied to a string, not datetime.

Comment: "Str" object has no attribute 'year'

Comment: This most likely means that `pd.to_datetime` was not applied to the dataframe that you are applying `.year/.month/.day` to.

Comment: I used "interactions['Review Date'] = pd.to_datetime(interactions['Review Date'], format = '%Y/%m/%d')" to change the type of the column from object to datetime. But still no luck ..

Comment: But in your screenshot the format is  `'%Y-%m-%d'`. I think you can remove format altogether, `to_datetime` will recognize it anyway as it is standard.